# Remove anchor tags using jQuery

Tags: jquery

My html:

```
<div class="example">
   <a id="link" href="http://www.google.com">Example</a>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('a#link').remove();
```

What I would like to do, is make the html look like this after the `<a>` tag is removed:

```
<div class="example">
  Example
</div>
```

How do I remove just the

```
<a> </a>
```

part?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Alternate solution:

```
$("a#link").replaceWith($("a#link").text());
```

Comment: Do you mean `$("#example").html($('#example').text());`

Comment: @Vega: Yes I do, I always get that screwed up... I edited it out anyhow.

Comment: I happened upon this just now. It'll fail horribly when you want to handle multiple links. It's also significantly overkill.

Answer (score 17):

[`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents) gets the children *including* text nodes.

[`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap) removes parent element while keeping the selected nodes.

These functions have been available since jQuery 1.4 which was released in 2010:

```js
$('#link').contents().unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example">
   <a id="link" href="http://www.google.com">Example</a>
</div>
```

It'll also work if you have multiple nodes in your selection:

```js
$('a').contents().unwrap();
```

```css
.one {
  color: red;
}
.two {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
  <a href="#">Foo</a>
</div>
<div class="two">
  <a href="#">Bar</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

To remove `a` but retain its text try:

```
$('.example').html($('.example a#link').text());
```

or

```
$('.example a#link').replaceWith($('.example a#link').text());
```

Comment: Why was this voted down? +1 because it's a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville May be it was down voted for his earlier revisions. Well I didn't down vote, but just saying.. however down voting without a comment is really annoying.

Comment: @Vega surprise, surprise!! thanks.. always wish help from yours.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the `a` element entirely:

```
// this approach is sloppy, but essentially it
// selects the element whose id is equal to 'link',
// finds the parent, and sets that parent's text
// to the text of the '#link' element:
$('#link').parent().text($('#link').text());
```

```js
$('#link').parent().text($('#link').text());
```

```css
a::after {
  content: ' (a element).';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example">
  <a id="link" href="http://www.google.com">Example</a>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rTQ6K/66/).

The approach is 'sloppy' because we select the same element twice, rather than
caching a reference or using the inherent properties of a a given node.

Or:

```
// here we again find the parent of the given '#link'
// element, and update its text using the anonymous 
// function of the text() method:
$('#link').parent().text(function(i, text) {
  // i:    the first argument, is the index of the
  //       current element amongst the jQuery
  //       collection returned by the selector,
  // text: the second argument, is the existing
  //       text of the node prior to modification
  //       within the function.

  // here we simply return the same text, which
  // replaces the existing innerHTML of the
  // node with only the text:
  return text;
});
```

```js
$('#link').parent().text(function(i, text) {
  return text;
});
```

```css
a::after {
  content: ' (a element).';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example">
  <a id="link" href="http://www.google.com">Example</a>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rTQ6K/68/).

Or, rather more concisely:

```
// here we find the element, access its contents
// (its childNodes) and unwrap those contents,
// with the unwrap() method, to remove the parent
// element of the contents and replace that parent
// with its contents:
$('#link').contents().unwrap();
```

```js
$('#link').contents().unwrap();
```

```css
a::after {
  content: ' (a element).';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example">
  <a id="link" href="http://www.google.com">Example</a>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rTQ6K/67/).

Or even with plain JavaScript:

```
function removeAndRetain(node) {

  // caching references to the passed-in node,
  // and that node's parentNode:
  var el = node,
    parent = el.parentNode;

  // while the passed-in node has a firstChild:
  while (el.firstChild) {

    // we insert that firstChild before the
    // passed-in node, using parent.insertBefore():
    parent.insertBefore(el.firstChild, el);
  }

  // here we explicitly remove the passed-in node
  // from the document, using Node.removeChild():
  parent.removeChild(el);
}

removeAndRetain(document.getElementById('link'));
```

```js
function removeAndRetain(node) {
  var el = node,
    parent = el.parentNode;

  while (el.firstChild) {
    parent.insertBefore(el.firstChild, el);
  }
  parent.removeChild(el);
}

removeAndRetain(document.getElementById('link'));
```

```css
a::after {
  content: ' (a element).';
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <a id="link" href="http://www.google.com">Example</a>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rTQ6K/71/).

And, to improve the above approach, allowing it to take and work with multiple nodes:

```
function removeAndRetain(node) {

  // if Array.from() exists, we use that otherwise we
  // use an alternative method to convert the supplied node,
  // NodeList, HTMLCollection... into an Array:
  var nodes = Array.from ? Array.from(node) : Array.prototype.slice.call(node, 0),

  // initialising a variable for use in the
  // (later) loop:
    parent;


  // using Array.prototype.forEach() to iterative over
  // the Array of nodes:
  nodes.forEach(function(n) {
    // n: the first argument, is a reference to the 
    // current element of the Array over which
    // we're iterating.

    // assigning the current-node's parent to
    // parent variable:
    parent = n.parentNode;

    // as above, here we move the firstChild from
    // the current-node to become its previous
    // sibling:
    while (n.firstChild) {
      parent.insertBefore(n.firstChild, n);
    }

    // removing the current-node from the document:
    parent.removeChild(n);

    // normalizing the parent, so that adjacent
    // textNodes are merged together:
    parent.normalize();
  });
}

removeAndRetain(document.querySelectorAll('.example a'));
```

```js
function removeAndRetain(node) {
  var nodes = Array.from ? Array.from(node) : Array.prototype.slice.call(node, 0),
    parent;

  nodes.forEach(function(n) {
    parent = n.parentNode;

    while (n.firstChild) {
      parent.insertBefore(n.firstChild, n);
    }
    parent.removeChild(n);
    parent.normalize();
  });
}

removeAndRetain(document.querySelectorAll('.example a'));
```

```css
a::after {
  content: ' (a element).';
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <a id="link" href="http://www.google.com">Example1</a>
</div>
<div class="example">
  <a href="http://www.google.com">Example2</a>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rTQ6K/72/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).
  - [`node.normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/normalize).
  - [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).
  - [`Node.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild).
  - [`while (...)` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while).
- jQuery:

  - [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).
  - [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
  - [`unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/).

Comment: He want's to remove the <a> tag itself, not just the href

Answer (score 0):

You have to use find(), contents() and unwrap() together to jQuery remove anchor tag link.

```
jQuery('.myDiv').find('a').contents().unwrap();
```

Answer (score -1):

I met the same problem - to remove 'a' tags from text. I'm not sure if other solutions care about efficiency - all of them do the element searching twice. Moreover, the accepted solution doesn't work properly in case there are multiple `'a#link'` elements, e.g.:

```
<div class="example">
  <a id="link" href="http://www.google.com">Example 1</a>
  <a id="link" href="http://www.google.com">Example 2</a>
  <a id="link" href="http://www.google.com">Example 3</a>
</div>
```

So this is another yet solution which doesn't try to find the element twice and works correctly with multiple elements:

```
$('a#link').each(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Suppose a linked text:

`<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" class="link-style">MY link</a>`

Use below code to just remove the link (href), but keep the styling defined on **link-style** class:

```
jQuery(".post-meta").find('a').each(function () {
    var obj = jQuery(this);
    obj.removeAttr("href");
});
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question that was asked.